# SFMC Report Tool - Transformation

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I am trying to understand If I can transform or merge some of values in report tool. For example Under Report tool, I am using "Blank Template for Email Sending Performance" and I am running this report base on campaign name. Every one of my email have campaign name associated. But for some campaign I want to merge them into one.

Lets say Currently report shows like this.

```
Campaign name           SEND           OPEN
Billing Alert 1         100             60
Billing Alert 2         50              10
Billing Alert 3         10              4
Email A                 1000            x
Email B                 204             x
```

I want to make it like this

```
Campaign name           SEND           OPEN
Billing Alerts          160             74
Email A                 1000            x
Email B                 204             x
```

Do you have any idea, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are the emails you are trying to group on automations or triggers?  I ask, because if the names are static, or always have the same prefix you could use [Substring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm) and [Add](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Add.htm).

Comment: Email Names are always static.